# IntelliJ Idea under Linux, No such file or directory on main class

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, java

I'm running IntelliJ Idea under linux. I have created a project and a module inside it, and in that module I have a class (MyClass.class) and when I'm trying to run it from IDE, I get

> ERROR: MyClass.class (No Such file or directory)

Can somebody explain me why IntelliJ Idea doesn't recognize the classes inside my module? I know it should be a problem regarding module settings but I can't figure it out. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

OK I place here the paths and everything for all to see :)

**type** : echo $PATH
**Result:**
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin

**type:** echo $JAVA_HOME
**Result:**
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

**type:** ./idea.sh
**Result:** 
NOTE: If you have both Sun JDK and OpenJDK installed
please validate either IDEA_JDK or JDK_HOME environment variable points to valid Sun JDK installation

Comment: I also have the same problem. Intelij Idea community edition on ubuntu 11.10. Compiles ok with javac, but gives an error in IDE(No such file)

Comment: Try to remove all JSDK and add them again in intelij idea, both the jdk6 and jdk7 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arkde, I have a possible explanation why Jaroslav's solution with JDK7 didn't work for you.

Maybe you had mixed Java versions in various **alternatives** items, possibly conflicting with the version that environment variables like `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` point to?

Maybe something points to the `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` symlink as the JDK home, and that symlink points to a different version of JDK than intended?

Did you try resetting alternatives for all Java tools to version 7? Like this:

```
update-java-alternatives --list
# ...see what JDK's are available, choose the one that corresponds to Java 7
# and set it to be the default in alternatives:
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
# or interactively:
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

What do the following commands output on your system?

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $JDK_HOME
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
update-java-alternatives --list
update-alternatives --list java
```

I had exactly the same problem.
I've performed strace on the Idea process and in the log I saw it trying to open several .class files without the path to them specified - like `open("SomeClass.class", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` - no path to the project output directory and to appropriate package.

So I've apt-get installed JDK 7 along JDK 6:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-doc openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib openjdk-7-source
```

In Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric, OpenJDK 6 isn't removable if you want OpenJDK 7. JDK 7 is dependent on JDK 6...

So I've:

1. updated alternatives configuration as specified above,
2. changed the `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` symlink to point to `java-7-openjdk-amd64` ,
3. double checked all the environment variables (my `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` both point to `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`),
4. reconfigured my project's SDK appropriately (and for all the modules in the project),

and voila - problem solved!

Answer (score 5):

Solved it. Remove all jdk/jre you have, install openjdk7.

Add this line to .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Run Idea. Profit. :)

Comment: Well I don't know how you did it but it is not working. Seems that IDEA is not working with openJDK7.

Comment: InteliJ woun't start with java-7-openjdk and if Install default jdk, the problem persist

Comment: Add that line to .bashrc turn on the terminal, cd into the intelij/bin directory and run ./idea.sh and tell my your output.

Comment: I did that and I get this when I'm trying to run ./idea.sh : No JDK found to run IDEA. Please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation. This is not happening if I have default java installed but it does when i have java-7-openjdk

Comment: Type in the terminal
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/your path to openjdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
then cd into directory and it should work.

Comment: Check my post again for latest results after I did what you said :) I have edit it so all can see it :) Thanks,Arkde

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem.  What I found is that the underlying system-wide Java version doesn't matter, so there is no need to set `JAVA_HOME` or `update_alternatives`.  All I had to do was change some settings in IDEA:

- Add a Java SDK, either OpenJDK 7, or Oracle JDK 6 or 7 (`File -> Project structure -> SDKs`)
- Select it as Project SDK (`File -> Project structure -> Project`)

Answer (score 0):

Check that **Make** checkbox is enabled, otherwise IDEA will not compile your project, also verify that class file is available in the output directory and you are running with the classpath of the correct module.

If the problem remains, send a sample project to support.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not working. I have make enable, classes are in output directory, and the module is correct... still same problem

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem - I moved my projects (and Idea settings) from a laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 and sun-jdk-6 to a PC with Ubunty 11.10 and openjdk-6. Upon project rebuild I got `MyClass.class (No Such file or directory)` errors for ALL classes.

Thanks to Jaroslav, his (almost) solution did helped - I can't explain why, perhaps it would work with sun-jdk-6 too... So, I installed openjdk-7, without removing openjdk-6, and set 7th as a project's JDK in Idea. (I did not change anything in environment variables.) With jdk7 it compiled.

PS I should've written it as a comment to Jaroslav's post, not a separate answer, but I don't yet have enough reputation to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Try to run IDEA using

`sh -c "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386 && ./idea.sh"`

When it starts press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S` to open *Project Settings* dialog. In the left panel choose **Project** and verify that **Project SDK** is configured correctly (at least it is not red).