# IntelliJ MyClass.class (No such file or directory) when running application

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run my android application on IntelliJ. I created a project from existing source, and I've attached the SDK correctly, everything runs ok until there, but when I try to run, it logs messages saying:

```
Error: MyClass.class (No such file or directory)
```

And this happens with all classes I've created.

Any idea of what might be happening? Maybe some settings I must set in the IDE.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is first search in Google :) [Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031013/intelij-idea-under-linux-no-such-file-or-directory-on-main-class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it! In intelliJ go in **Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler** and in the **Use Compiler** choose javac in-process (Java6+ only).