# IntelliJ doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IntelliJ MyClass.class (No such file or directory) when running application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347949/intellij-myclass-class-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-application)

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA because so many people says it is much better compared with Eclipse.
I downloaded a lastest version, IntelliJ IDEA 11 UI.
However, after I created a Project with a default Module, and I created a java class named 'Example' as usually, compiled it, ran it, but just with error said that `Example.class (No such file or directory)`. It really confused me. Is it such a great IDE that I couldn't even run my program?!
Any thing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I just found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347949/intellij-myclass-class-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-application), `In intelliJ go in Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler and in the Use Compiler choose javac in-process (Java6+ only).` I tried it and it works! But I just cannot understand why?

Comment: What JDK vendor/version do you use? What's your OS? Did you run the class from the editor context menu?

Comment: I'm using openJDK 6.0 in Ubuntu 12.04, and I tried where I can find to run the class including context menu and menubar. Actually I can see Example.class was generated in the output classpath, but IntelliJ just said it couldn't find it.

Comment: It's a known problem with OpenJDK, please switch to Oracle JDK, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891.

Comment: Thanks. I did find my answer there.